# y axis ticks disappear in responsive chart in d3.js v4

Tags: d3.js

I had perfectly adequate ticks in my earlier statically sized plot using d3.js v4; once I made it resizable, the ticks and values disappeared from the y axis.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Plot Viewer</title>
    <script src="js/lib/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }

      #chart {
        position: fixed;
        left: 55px;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
        bottom: 55px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>

      var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
      var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");

      // parse the date time
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d %H:%M");

      function render() {

        $("svg").empty();

        // Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
        var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
        var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

        // Use the extracted size to set the size of an SVG element.
        svg
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        var margin = {top: 10, right: 15, bottom: 55, left: 55};
          width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the line
        var line = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.solar); });

        // Get the data
        d3.csv("data_fred.csv", function(error, data) {
          if (error) throw error;

          // format the data
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.time = parseTime(d.time);
            d.solar = +d.solar;
          });

          // Scale the range of the data
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.solar; })]);

          // Add the valueline path.
          svg.append("path")
              .data([data])
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", line);

          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d %H:%M  ")));

          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
              .ticks(10);
        });
      } 

      render();

      // Redraw based on the new size whenever the browser window is resized
      window.addEventListener("resize", render);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The submitter function wants more details, but I have none...
blah
blah
blah
blah
characters added to pad non-code content.

The ticks are now gone on the y axis. I've added the .tick attribute to the y axis, but no joy.

How do I get my y axis ticks back on this responsive version of the chart? TIA

Posted later: Anyone? My non-responsive version of the code is drawing correctly; "responsifying" it makes the y-axis ticks and units disappear. I've tried almost every permutation of command ordering and placement, but no luck.

Comment: please provide axample working code

Comment: It's all here... just not the data file, which is of the format: time,solar
11/30 04:55,-1.1
11/30 05:00,-1.1
11/30 05:05,-1.5
11/30 05:10,-1.5 which does not present well in the comment section ;-)

Comment: solar reaches a peak of ~ 800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - the axis ticks were disappearing off the left edge of the window - fixed that with a transform/translate:

```
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(40 ,10)")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

...with a similar translation of the x axis and path to match.

Also, the axis scale now appeared with an extent of 0 to 1.0, as it wasn't being passed out of the file read loop since it was an asynchronous operation. Bringing the svg.append's into the data read loop restored my "normal" units to the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening here is your Y axis ticks are getting hidden because they're not in the viewport. What you need to do is put all the elements in your svg in a `<g>` wrapper and translate it by left and top margins.

Here's a fiddle

```js
var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");
var g = svg.append('g');

function render() {
  $('svg').empty();


  // Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
  var width = $('#chart').width();
  var height = $('#chart').height();

  // Use the extracted size to set the size of an SVG element.
  svg
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 40
  };
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // parse the date time
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d %H:%M");

  // set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  // define the line
  var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.time);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.solar);
    });

  // Get the data
  var data = [{
    'time': '11/30 04:55',
    'solar': -1.1
  }, {
    'time': '11/30 05:00',
    'solar': -1.1
  }, {
    'time': '11/30 05:05',
    'solar': -1.5
  }, {
    'time': '11/30 05:10',
    'solar': -2
  }, {
    'time': '11/30 05:15',
    'solar': 1
  }]
  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.time = parseTime(d.time);
    d.solar = +d.solar;
  });

  console.log(data)

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.time;
  }));
  var yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.solar;
  })
  y.domain(yExtent);

  g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // Add the valueline path.
  g.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d %H:%M  ")))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  // Add the Y Axis
  g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

}

//      d3.select("svg").remove();
//      svg.remove();
//      d3.selectAll("g > *").remove()
//        d3.selectAll("chartDiv.path.line").remove();
//      d3.select("path.line").remove();
render();

// Redraw based on the new size whenever the browser window is resized.
window.addEventListener("resize", render);
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hmm - that fiddle don't fiddle ;-) I admit to confusion on group attributes, but as I added the g.append("g") lines in place of the original svg.append("g") ones, the elements disappeared one by one. (path, x axis, y axis) and never did the y-axis ticks/values appear. What am I doing wrong?